# Long list of big images with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks, browser-cache, chromium

I have a very special problem. I need to display a long list (about 200-2000) of big images (1-4MB each) with angularjs. I have started with idea that I must show only a small part of images on the screen and mock the others not visible images with dummy top and bottom DOM elements. My solution is close to [linkedin smooth infinite scrolling](https://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5).

It is working as expected: i have a small amount of DOM elements for very long lists (usually about 10 visible items). You can look at demo [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MMK671FN6DnfKDRtlL1O?p=preview). I post some HTML code here to illustrate the idea:

```
<light-scroll name="images" 
              class="list">
    <!-- top dummy DOM element with dynamic height will be placed here-->

    <!-- transcluded part of visible items -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in visibleItems track by item.url"
         id="{{ item.url }}"
         ng-click="doSomeJob(item)"
         class="list-item">
         <img height="300"
              hide-till-loaded="item.markAsLoaded()"
              defer-src-loaded="item.loaded"
              defer-src="item.url">
         <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
     </div>

     <!-- bottom dummy DOM element with dynamic height will be placed here-->
</light-scroll>
```

#### The problem

While testing this code with long lists (usually about 200-500 images) application sometimes causes crashes. Crashes cannot be easily replicated but they happen.

#### My Research

I used Chrome Task Manager to view memory usage for my application. It is quite big: from 300MB to 1.5GB. So i came to the idea that i have a memory problem.

I thought the problem is in my code and i have a memory leak somewhere. And i started to use Chrome Dev Tools (Timeline and Profiles) as described on [Google Developers Memory Diagnosis page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis) and [Eliminating memory leaks in Gmail](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wUVmf78gG-ra5aOxvTfYdiLkdGaR9OhXRnOlIcEmu2s/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.g1d65bdf6_0_0)

I could not find any leaks but i found an interesting regularity.

1. If i scroll the list not often (like scroll to bottom, then wait 20-30 sec, then scroll again, then wait again etc.) Garbage Collector works fine and cleans memory and DOM nodes. Here you can see Timeline results:
   [image]
2. If i scroll aggressively (fast to top, fast to bottom, then middle, then bottom etc.) without any pauses, Garbage Collector cannot clean memory and DOM nodes. Here Timelines again:
   [image]

The same results i have while monitoring Task Manager. After 30-60 sec pauses memory usually comes down.

### The questions

1. Can you suggest any other ways to detect memory leaks?
2. Does browser keep all the images in memory and cannot garbagecollect them for some reason?
3. Can you suggest any solutions to this cache or/and memory problem?
4. Can you suggest any other ideas about implementation of long lists with big images?

#### Notes

I'm not using thumbnails as i need a cached full resolution image for immediate future work later in my workflow. I can force the user to wait while scrolling the list, but i cannot force him to wait when he clicks on image and starts working with it.

I have tried to reuse ng-repeat DOM elements with `track by $index` option. Yes, it helps a bit about number of DOM nodes but memory still grows to big values.